# What's the benefit of Band Steering when both bands work anyway?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, dual-band

I have a computer that can connect to a Technicolor DGA2232 router both via 2.4 and 5 GHz. As we all know, 2.4 is better for distance while 5 is better for speed.

But when the router's band steering option is turned on (which is how it is by default) the computer only uses 2.4.

With band steering turned off, the computer can connect to the 5 Ghz WiFi. As soon as it does, the speed is very high.

So with band steering on, why does the router think it's better to give this computer 2.4? Is it more stable? If so, how do you define "stable" in that context?

[image: Band Steering option]

Comment: Please consider deleting your comment since you also made it into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Band Steering Threshold is set to a reasonably "high" value (i.e. it will only switch to 5Ghz when the 2.4GHz signal strength is <-50dBm, which is a high value).

What if you set the Band Steering Threshold to a different value? Try values between -60 to -70dBm and see if that works.

Also make sure all of the parameters like SSID, security type and password match between 2.4 and 5GHz.

Answer (score 0):

The router doesn't yet know which band is better. So it's directing the client to connect to the 2.4GHz band because that has the highest likelihood of working due to its greater range. Once the client connects on the 2.4GHz band, the router will make a decision whether to switch it to the 5GHz band.

Comment: Makes sense. But I'm talking about a case in which it stays with 2.4 indefinitely, even though with band steering off it has no problem connecting to 5 with great speeds.

Comment: You may want to reduce the band steering threshold then. The router probably didn't think the 2.4GHz connection was strong enough.

Comment: I assume you meant 5, not 2.4, @david-schwartz. In any case it was already submitted as another answer.

Comment: @LWC No, 2.4GHz. There is no 5GHz connection in this case. Unless the 2.4GHz connection is very strong, the router asumes that the 5GHz connection (which will typically be weaker) is not a good idea if the client didn't opt for it.

Comment: So you say the router just makes an assumption that if 2.4 is not strong enough, surely the 5 will be even worse? Why not checking 5 directly?

Comment: @LWC Generally they'll assume that if despite earlier band steering attempts, the device still connected over 2.4GHz and the resulting connection was weak, that means 5GHz won't work or will work worse. The earlier band steering logic may have, for example, only heard the device making probing requests on 2.4Ghz or heard weak probing requests on 5GHz.

Comment: Why not check 5 first and go to 2.4 is 5 is not strong enough? Why is 2.4 the default?

Comment: @LWC That is sort of what happens. There is no standard for band steering, so it's kind of an improvised mechanism. Typically, an AP will ignore probes from clients for a short period of time, look at whether it has reeived probes on both bands, and if so, prefer to reply on the 5GHz band if the probes are sufficiently strong. But if it gets a weak 2.4Ghz link, it generally will not try to move the client.